# Was there a Morascini (Morrasini) on Italian naval roster anywhere during 19th century?

Tags: 19th-century, military-records, italy

I am looking for a family connection to seafaring in 19th century.

The Morascini (Morrasini) family were located in the lower Alps region of northern Italy.

Was there a Morascini (Morrasini) on Italian naval roster anywhere during 19th century?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  As it stands your question is quite broad.  Is there any source that you have found that suggests there may be a "connection to seafaring in 19th century" for this family?  If so, then referencing that would help any potential answerers help you.

Comment: You may find this to be a useful starting point to your search: https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Italy_Military_Records